# react native svg LinearGradient apply to d3-shape arc seems werid

Tags: d3.js, svg, react-native

what confuse me is the way that the gradient color apply to arc, it seems not right, seems the colors cut off from special location, because of that the gradient color seems not gradient from start color to end color,
here is the code:

```
'use strict';
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import {View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'

import Svg, {Defs, Stop, G, Path, LinearGradient, Line} from 'react-native-svg'
import {arc} from 'd3-shape'


export default class TestPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    let rIn, rOut, rMiddle, startAngle, endAngle;
    rIn = 50;//inner circle radius
    rOut = 55;//outer circle radius
    rMiddle = 52.5;//middle circle radius
    startAngle = 0;//start angle 0
    endAngle = 300;//end angle 300

    let circlePath = arc()
      .innerRadius(rIn)
      .outerRadius(rOut)
      .cornerRadius(rMiddle - rIn)
      .startAngle(startAngle)
      .endAngle(2 * Math.PI / 360 * endAngle);

    return (
      <View style={Styles.wrap}>
        <View style={{width: 300, height: 200, backgroundColor: '#000000', marginTop: 2}}>
          <Svg width={300} height={200}>
            <Defs>
              <LinearGradient
                id={'wholeArcLengthLine'}
                x1={0}
                y1={0}
                x2={(2 * Math.PI * rMiddle * endAngle / 360).toFixed(2)}
                y2={0}>
                <Stop offset="0" stopColor={"#ff0000"}/>
                <Stop offset="0.36" stopColor={"#ef52a3"}/>
                <Stop offset="0.7" stopColor={"#b445dd"}/>
                <Stop offset="1" stopColor={"#0000ff"}/>
              </LinearGradient>
            </Defs>

            <G>
              <Line
                x={5}
                y={10}
                x1={0}
                y1={0}
                x2={(2 * Math.PI * rMiddle * endAngle / 360).toFixed(2)}
                y2={0}
                stroke={'url(#wholeArcLengthLine)'}
                strokeWidth="5"/>

              <Path
                x={100}
                y={100}
                d={circlePath()}
                fill={'url(#wholeArcLengthLine)'}/>
            </G>
          </Svg>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

const Styles = StyleSheet.create({
  wrap: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
  },
});
```

and here is the result, the arc gradient color is different from the Line colr:
[image]

so why?

and version:

> react: 16.0.0-alpha.12
>
> react-native: 0.45.1
>
> react-native-svg: 5.2.0
>
> d3-shape: 1.2.0